# addEventListener returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

addEventListener is simply not working as it should

I have a function where event listener is need to listen for scroll and then it calls a function as a callback.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", checkPosition);
```

It doesn't work at all. When I console log it it returned 'Undefined'. Any ideas why? I am using Google Chrome.

Thank you

Comment: The code for checkPosition will be needed for us to check

Comment: do you have height 100% on body or html tag? That would disable scroll event listener.

Comment: I just started this and I am just doing a console.log in it to see if its called

Comment: Note that `Undefined` is the expected return type for addEventListener (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Return_value)). Have you tried logging from within your `checkPosition` function to ensure it is called?

Comment: @Avanthika Thank you. It is working. Never would have tought about that. Thanks

Comment: Problem was 100% height on body. Silly me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that body had

```
height: 100%;
```

Thanks to @Avanthika who pointed it out